# Is there a way to enforce local=1 using environment variables instead of passing through URL parameters for Draw.io?

Tags: draw.io

Using Draw.io, I would like to enforce only using local device as storage.  This can be done via passing a URL parameter but can I do it via environment variable instead?  Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do what you want, but not with environment variable but modifying index.hhtml.
I guess if you ask this question, you use the offline version, so you can edit index.html.

You have just to edit the var params.

- before :

  ```
  var params = window.location.search.slice(1).split('&');
  ```
- after :

  ```
  var params = ["dev=1", "local=1", "offline=1"];
  ```

Comment: Our company doesn't allow cloud based storage for security and privacy reasons.  I am building the system in Openshift and running inhouse.  Can you let me know what dev=1 does?

Comment: PS.  Worked like a charm.  I just added a SED command in the dockerfile.  THANKS!!

Comment: I think dev param is just for development mode so that is not necessary on production purpose.